# How to save thw current WebView URL on app close and load it back when next the app is reopen?

Tags: java, android, cookies, webview

How do I save the current URL of android studio web view when the app is closed and load that URL when next the app is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with shared preferences.
This is not the best way, but easy to use:
First get the url from your webview

```
String currentUrl = webView.getUrl();
```

Then save it with shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_TAG", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putString("URL_TAG", currentUrl ).apply();
```

Now the string is stored in shared preferences and you can get the value after an
app restart on this way:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_TAG", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String savedUrl = prefs.getString("URL_TAG", null);
```

And last set the url to your webview:

```
webview.loadUrl(savedUrl);
```

> Be sure, the YOUR_TAG and URL_TAG has still the same string value on
>   saving and receiving. Otherwise the stored String value wont found

More information to shared preferences can you find
[on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3624358/9610875) or on the [offical android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

**I hope I could help!**

Comment: .Should I implement this code in on create. When the app is first run there is no saved URL so how will I handle that.